# input number spinner for bootstrap doesn't work with jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use this source on my website for numeric input, and its good.
http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Input-Number-Spinner-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-Spinner.html

The problem is, that i wanted to add autocomplete to my search input, i found source for it:

```
`<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#inputBook').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        var searched = $('#inputBook').val();
        var fullurl = $('#hiddenurl').val() +    'Podpowiedz/getResult/' + searched;
        console.log(fullurl);
        $.getJSON(fullurl,function(result){
            //display suggestion code goes here
            var elements = [];
            $.each(result, function(i, val){
                elements.push(val.title);
            });
            $('#inputBook').autocomplete({
                source : elements
            });
        })
    })
})
</script>`
```

To make .autocomplete work, i needed also too add jquery-ui plugin:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

And when i add this plugin, Input Number Spinner stops to work. Also it adds strange triagles (?), don't know why.

Without jquery-ui, works perfectly:
[image: without]

With jquery-ui, doesn't work and there are strange triangles on left, don't know why:
[image: with]

Comment: can you create jsfidder for this ?

Comment: Odd.. i can't reproduce this bug on jsfiddle - it works there. In this case i would have to check my code once again and make sure if it is not my fault.. thanks for answer

Comment: enjoy!!. let me know if you requires any further assistance

Comment: No idea why.. but i switched their position in header, that ui is being loaded as **first** and spinner **second** and it works. It would be funny if i hadn't spend over an hour looking for mistake.. :\      //solved

Comment: hehee.. . ..happy coding...